# Is there a way to retain local storage in mobile browsers?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, local-storage, mobile-safari, progressive-web-apps

This question is more theoretical than practical, hence i do not have any code to show for it.I using a PWA application in mobiles and I'm storing data in the local storage. so far so good. But if I force clear (remove the application from running in the background), I believe the local storage gets cleared, which is not ideal. Is there any way to prevent the os or browser from automatically clearing the local storage?

Answer (score 2):

Some of the useful links which helps you understand the functionalities of local storage https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage

Instead use Service worker as [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-your-app-work-offline-with-the-power-of-javascript-685d968bcfbb/)