# App in iframe localstorage is deleted after a while and independent of non-iframe instance - only on mobile

Tags: iframe, mobile, local-storage

I have [a page](https://www.recoveringfromreligion.org/resources) with an iframe. This iframe contains [a React web app](https://rfr-resources.netlify.app). In production the page and app have two different origins but I get the same problem when I serve both from localhost. There are two problems:

1. localstorage data of the app (but not containing page) is deleted after some time passes (maybe 30 minutes?).
2. localstorage of A) the app in the iframe is independent of localstorage of B) the same app in another tab outside of an iframe. Changes made to localstorage in one of A or B are not reflected in the other after refreshing or closing/opening the tab. But if I have two tabs with A or two tabs with B and change localstorage in one, then I see the change in the other after refreshing it.

All of this only happens on my iPhone (I don't have another mobile device). It happens with both Chrome and Safari. I'm running iOS 16.5.1. Everything works fine on my Mac.

Why is this happening and how do I keep it from happening?

Comment: If you're serving them off of different ports, then even in `localhost` they have different origins and are considered cross-domain requests.

Comment: @EliezerBerlin, okay that's probably not an important observation then. It works for a while and then stops working (on mobile). And it works all the time on my laptop. So there's something about mobile browsing that's the problem.

Comment: It's likely very important. Your problem is probably happening because they're cross-domain requests. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63922558/safari-localstorage-not-shared-between-iframes-hosted-on-same-domain/64018207#64018207

Comment: Oh okay. This probably handles problem 2 above. I wonder why it works at all and only clears localstorage after some time passes, and only on mobile. This is actually the main problem. I don't really need to solve problem 2. I just thought that it was a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments https://stackoverflow.com/a/64018207/2833639
should give you a rough understanding on why you can't (simply) share the localStorage between the different instances.

The other problem of the local storage deletion on mobile devices can have multiple reasons, as the data is stored for the app context. You might have a system cleaner running on you device or app-data is getting cleared periodically by system daemons. As mentioned in [Is there a way to retain local storage in mobile browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58502987/2833639) there are ways to work around the limitations.

Hope it helps a bit.